# subtract a line from a file to all the lines from another file

Tags: bash

I'd like to subtract column by column a line from a file to all the lines from another one.

Input:`file1`

```
1 1 1 1
3 1 5 1
1 5 8 2
```

Input:`file2`

```
1 1 1 1
```

Desired output:`file3`

```
0 0 0 0
2 0 4 0
0 4 7 1
```

awk, sed?

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1   { for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i] = $i }
     FNR!=NR { for(i=1; i <NF; i++) $i -= a[i]; print }' file2 file1
```

This assumes that:

1. the relevant line in `file2` is always the first
2. the first line in `file2` and all lines in `file1` have the same number of columns
3. if there are multiple spaces between columns in `file1` you don't care to preserve them.

Comment: `NR>1` the same as `FNR!=NR` in this context. But more neatly and clearly :)

Comment: @MiniMax That breaks if `file2` has more than one line. _shrug_

Answer (score 0):

```
tr ' -' ' _' < file1 |          # dashes -> underscores per dc requirements
dc -e "
[q]sq                           # macro for quitting
[z :x     z0<a]sa               # macro for main stack -> array x[]
[z ;x -SM z0<b]sb               # macro for doing: stack M = stack[i]-x[i]
[LMdn32an zlk>c]sc              # macro for printing stack M elements
[?z0=q lbx lcx 10Pc z0=?]s?     # do-while loop to read in file1 per line and run the macros "b" then "c"
$(< file2 tr ' -' ' _')         # load up the main stack with file2
zsk lax l?x                     # store cols in reg. k, call macro "a" and
" > file3
```

---

### Results

```
0 0 0 0
2 0 4 0
0 4 7 1
```

---

### Assumptions

1. GNU dc
2. As many columns in file1 & file2, but they should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash solution.

**Usage:** `./subtracting.sh file1 file2`

```
#!/bin/bash

read -ra subtrahend < "$2"

while read -ra minuend; do
    for i in "${!minuend[@]}"; do
        echo -n $((minuend[$i] - subtrahend[$i]))
    done
    echo
done < "$1"
```